# How to describe someone whose voice or way of talking creates an anxious or uncomfortable feeling in others?

Tags: single-word-requests

I described someones voice as being **shrill** but I think that relates to the voice being particularly high pitched.

If when someone speaks and it invokes an uneasy feeling in others, how would you describe it? The uneasy feeling isn't necessarily from what they are saying but rather the tone, pitch, repetitiveness, etc.

I could generalize and say they are annoying or irritating but that isn't necessarily the case. Is there a word that is more accurate for this?

**So if someone talking can be uncomfortable to listen to how would you describe their voice?**

**Example use could be:**

- Blimey, your voice is quite ***word here***
- Woah, be quiet for a second, when you speak you're quite ***word here***

Comment: You could use the word coarse here.

Comment: You examples are very low register. All the suggestions are very high register. So.....low register: Blimey, your voice is getting on my nerves.

Comment: This question will have a thousand answers. :) Can you narrow down your question?

Comment: I thought (and hoped) we were going in a different direction with "way of talking". You're just talking about the sound of their voice? Title: "How would you describe someone's voice that's uncomfortable to listen to?"

Comment: Is this in a social context or a work of fiction? If the latter, you could describe the physical response of the person's hearers. (Standard show vs. tell.)

Comment: @Don Branson could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: The idea in fiction is that it's better to show than to tell - that is, instead of describing someone's voice, show how people respond to it. They fidget, or roll their eyes, or sigh, for example. That's often challenging. The result though, is that your reader connects with the hearer's emotions, and becomes more engaged than if they're told how to perceive the voice, i.e., grating.

Answer (score 17):

Consider *[grating](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/grating)*

> Sounding harsh and unpleasant:
>   *her high, grating voice*

Also *[strident](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/strident)*

> Loud and harsh; grating:
>   *his voice had become increasingly sharp, almost strident*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

And if you want a simile, you could say

> His voice is like *[fingernails on a chalkboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalkboard_scraping).*

Comment: grating is a good one

Answer (score 16):

"Distressing": *causing anxiety, sorrow or pain; upsetting.*

"Unsettling": *causing one to feel anxious or uneasy; disturbing.*

"Agitating": *make (someone) troubled or nervous.*

Comment: "Unsettling" is a good one.

Answer (score 8):

I like **[unnerving](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unnerving)**.

> making one feel worried or uncomfortable

Example ([Telstra's phone alarm service put to sleep](http://www.news.com.au/technology/wake-up-australia-telstras-phone-alarm-service-put-to-sleep/story-e6frfro0-1226527500570)):

> You rang the number, booked a time, then were rudely awoken from your
>   blissful slumber by that lady with the annoying and slightly unnerving
>   voice that sounded like a computer.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the term "[***creepy***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/creepy)", which seems to fit your description very well.

> Adjective creepy ‎(comparative creepier, superlative creepiest)
>
> Producing an uneasy fearful sensation, as of things crawling over
>   one's skin. Strangely repulsive.

Comment: creepy is a good shout, but not quite what I was after. it's a less creepy/nervous feeling, more annoyed or irritated feeling.

Comment: that's the one - for me, at least

Comment: If that's the case, I'd probably go with your original answer, **shrill**, or most of the examples suggested by @bib.  Of his suggestions I think I like **strident** the best.

Answer (score 1):

***aggravating***

> :  arousing displeasure, impatience, or anger.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggravating)

Answer (score 0):

I also quite like *grating* and *agitating* (and voted on them). You could also go with the more blunt *anxiety-inducing*. Another question to consider is, what sort of uncomfortable feeling does the speaker provoke? Is it a general snakes-in-the-gut creepiness, or social embarrassment for their lack of awareness, or something else? Is it provoked by the words they use, or the timbre of their voice? Thinking about those things may help you land on the right term. Best of luck!

Comment: Good questions. Not creepy. Lack of awareness maybe. Its very hard to explain the feeling. They might simply be sooo monotone that it invokes the feeling. Or they might be high pitched and annoying and it invokes the same feeling. Grating, aggitating, are closest so far.

Comment: I saw Don Branson's bit above about show vs. tell, and that could be a great tool depending on your context:  "Blimey, your voice gives me the shivers!" or "Blimey, your voice is ice on my bones"-- etc.,-- you could use the speaker's description of their own reaction to illustrate the interlocutor's voice. Hope that helps!

Comment: I didnt understand that comment. Meant to respond to it

Comment: Mostly used in fiction writing, you show the reader the story rather than telling with a litany of straight statements.   Tell: "Sam was unnerved by the news."  vs.   Show: "Sam's grip on the letter tightened, and he stumbled into a chair as his knees failed him."   That kind of stuff.